# Define animation for ng-view in AngularJS in routing configuration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have seen various workaround for animating ng-view forward and backward when a button is tapped/clicked on for Angular 1.2. This involves having a method on your scope that will set a  scope variable to a page/animation that is used in ng-class to set a class on the element that has ng-view directive on it. On a larger app, this doesn't seem very scalable. Part of it I believe would be that you'd create a service/factory to inject into the controller to not duplicate code. But I'm really wondering if there's something you can do in the router resolve  functionality where you set some values for animation there and send them to a service that returns a promise that is immediately resolved. This could set the class on the ng-view element before the route changes and possibly manage it this way.

Does anyone have a more defined way to handle animating ng-view in forward and reverse depending on what route the user is going to?

Comment: Here a link that surely will interest you : http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngView#animations

Comment: I think ngAnimate is exactly what you are looking for, but be aware that this module was modified in 1.2 and CSS animations from 1.1.4 won't work in 1.2. http://slid.es/gsklee/animation-in-angularjs-12 - here you can see the nice overview of changes.

Comment: Yep, totally understand how to do it the official 1.2 way. looking for a more scalable solution to do it in the route config that will also support going in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concept I've been playing with and am able to get to work within views for some repeater elements. I haven't gotten it to the point of animating `ng-view` yet....but should give you a good starting point.

Concept is to store an `ng-animate` object in each route config. 
You can pass a scope object to `ng-animate` with no expression needed.

```
function Ctrl($scope){
   $scope.ANIM={enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'};
}

<li ng-animate="ANIM">
```

In Config:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/foo', {
                controller: 'Ctrl',
                templateUrl:'view1.html',
                anim:{enter: 'skew-enter', leave: 'skew-leave'}
            })
```

Then in `run()` listen for `$routeChangeStart` and get animation from current route config

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
            $rootScope.anim={enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, current){               
                $rootScope.anim=  current.anim 
            })
        })
```

In my sandbox version I do:

```
 function Ctrl($scope, $rootScope){
       $scope.ANIM=$rootScope.anim;
    }
```

Again...this is still at proof of concept stage. When I have 2 views with same ng-animate and within each controller make `$scope.anim=$rootScope.anim` it works.

hope this helps...be curious if you do anything more with it

Answer (score 0):

What i've found to work is making use of css subclasses, so that in your container you have a binding to a property called "mode" or something along those lines.

then its a case of getting those to change whenever you want to switch animation, whether this is using $routeChangeSuccess or something else is up to you.